# Set transaction fee

Tags: bitcoind

I am using the `bitcoind` API to send transactions from my account to user accounts. I have found, that the `sendtoaddress` method uses `address,amount and comment` to send transactions, but I need to set comission for each transaction. Please help me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the fee (commission) paid with the settxfee RPC command:

> bitcoin-cli settxfee 0.00045

Comment: How can i check the size of transaction ? 
I have already found answers in `stackoverflow`. but can not understood, how can i check the size of `transaction` before sending